# Canvas not redrawing after deletion in Group (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

I have background (`Rectangle`) and `Group` added into `root` of canvas. I add smaller `Rectangle` (player) into group and then move rectangle by AnimationTimer (custom without thread sleep). When small `Rectangle` arrive centrain X position I want to remove this Rectangle from scene. After deletion, rectangle remains in canvas until I move/resize window. How to refresh canvas to make deleted rectangle disappear?

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 50;
    public static final int WIDTH = 15;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 15;

    public static final int FRAMERATE = 30;

    private Pane root;

    private Group group = new Group();

    private Rectangle player;

    private Parent createContent() {
        root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(500, 500);
        bg.setFill(Color.RED);

        root.getChildren().addAll(bg, group);

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                onUpdate();
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        player = new Rectangle(20, 20);
        player.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        group.getChildren().add(player);

        return root;
    }

    public void onUpdate() {

        if (player.getTranslateY() > 100) {
            group.getChildren().remove(player);
        } else {
            player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() + 1);
            player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() + 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087752), which is still unresolved.

The workarounds suggested in the bug report are to disable dirty region optimizations, which you can do by providing the JVM option `-Dprism.dirtyopts=false`, i.e. run it as

```
java -Dprism.dirtyopts=false Test
```

You can also set this programmatically if your `main` method is in a class separate to the `Application` subclass (because you need to set it before the `Application` class is loaded):

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("prism.dirtyopts", "false");
        Application.launch(Test.class, args);
    }
}
```

(and then just run the `App` class in the usual way).

Another workaround seems to be to ensure there is a more complex change to the group's list of child nodes, but this is not likely to be very robust. For example, the following seems to work in this particular case.

```
public void onUpdate() {


    if (player.getTranslateY() > 100) {
        Rectangle dummy = new Rectangle();
        group.getChildren().add(dummy);
        group.getChildren().remove(player);
        group.getChildren().remove(dummy);
    } else {
        player.setTranslateX(player.getTranslateX() + 1);
        player.setTranslateY(player.getTranslateY() + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So this happening only if you remove last node in group? Thats why you created and then removed dummy?

Comment: @Baterka Not sure. I got that solely by trial and error. You could search on JDKBugs and see if this is known and if there are better workarounds. It seems to be specific to `Group`, so if you can get away with a `Pane` instead, that's your best option, but I assume you chose `Group` for the way it manages layout